# Is there an R function to disconnect and reconnect to a network?

Tags: r, odbc, r-dbi

I am writing a report in R that needs to be automated. The report connects to a database in SQL Server using `DBI::dbConnect()` and `odbc::odbc()` (`conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), "db_name")`) . 80% of the time the connection works a treat, but the other 20% of the time we get the following error message:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HYT00: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired
```

This has been a known error for a while and the workaround is to just unplug from the network (disconnect from the internet etc.) and the plug back in (reconnect). This fixes the problem 9 times out of 10 (the other time you just need to do the fix again and it will work). The problem is, this fix is obviously very manual won't work for automated reports. Does anyone know of a function/method to disconnect and reconnect to a network programatically in R?

Comment: Okay, so it turns out that I should have given more t thought to the error message. It turns out that the default timeout for dbConnect is 10 seconds, but sometimes this connection takes longer than that (maybe when others are querying the server?). The fix I found is just to modify the timeout argument in the dbConnect function. I have set it to 240 seconds. I would still be interested to know if it is possible to disconnect and reconnect to a network in R, so I will leave this question open.